# Rotate wallpapers per batch

Tags: batch-file, wallpaper

We need a batch for changing the wallpapers at logon and after that change it every T minutes.

What I already found is
    `reg add "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop" /v Wallpaper /f /t REG_SZ /d path_of_image
RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters`

This works good for one particular image. But we have a couple of images to switch. Is there a possible way to set a folder per batch?

Comment: Have you considered employing the built-in task scheduler for that?

Comment: Yes I have looked at the task scheduler. But the purpose of this is that we want to apply that to every machine of our domain.

Comment: So far I had to change my plans since I could not get any solution. Now I'm trying to deploy a themepack to every computer by a simple batch `start /min serverlocation\mytheme.deskthemepack` 
This works, but i lefts always the control panel open. How is it possible to kill that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to second what Andriy M suggested in using task scheduler, as you mentioned you wanted to push it to every machine in your domain have you considered using a GPO to push that out?

The Microsoft walkthrough on using GPO to assign a scheduled task is here:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx

I would probably use two separate tasks for it, one triggered by logon and then one triggered on a set amount of time (i.e. once every 15 minutes).

I'm a huge fan of GPO as you can use it for everything from requiring password changes to blocking the ask toolbar from installing.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. We solved the problem by using GPO. But instead of the task scheduler we deployed whole themes already configurated with out wallpapers.